# What should our main site chatroom be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site has at least one chatroom associated to it. The primary chatroom for the site usually has an interesting name which is somehow evocative of the topic of that site: for instance, [the h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) at [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) at [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) at [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com).

**What should we call [the main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/literature) for Literature SE?**

Comment: Based on the answers and the voting so far, I'm led to conclude that the libraries I frequent must be wholly different to the ones majority of users frequent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The Reading Room

Is there a more obvious pick?

Comment: I thought The Library was more obvious ... but yes, +1 to this too :-)

Comment: I'll second this. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 22):

## The Book Club

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_discussion_club):

> A **book discussion club** is a group of people who meet to discuss a book or books that they have read and express their opinions, likes, dislikes, etc. It is more often called simply a **book club**.

Answer (score 12):

### The Library.

An obvious choice, I think?

Comment: SHUSH! No talking in the library! </Madam_Pince>

Comment: Yes, because everyone knows libraries are where people gather to chat. :P

Comment: @DJMcMayhem they do now. Libraries are (quietly) teeming with activity.

Comment: That's the name of the chat room for Biblical Hermeneutics.SE, in case there's a reason to avoid duplication (besides my convenience).

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh. I didn't know that :-(

Comment: I'm deleting this answer because as @Nathaniel points out, "The Library" would be a duplicate of another main site chatroom.

Comment: I'm undeleting this answer because we may as well have it on record as a rejected suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

## The Bookcase

Full of books :)

Answer (score 2):

The Reading Nook seems like a good name

Answer (score 2):

## The Book Nook.

A little late to the party, but I thought I'd throw this in there for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to go to ***The Library***.

Comment: This was actually the first suggestion I posted, but then I deleted it after learning that "The Library" is the name of [hermeneutics.se] SE's main site chatroom.

Answer (score -1):

While a mite pretentious, "**[Salon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salon_(gathering))**" seems appropriate, to mirror real world for gatherings that discussed literature (among other things).

Comment: I like this a lot. Screw pretentiousness; it's appropriate and doesn't have SHUSH WE'RE READING connotations. A salon is where you were *supposed* to have intellectual discourse.

Comment: Like...a beauty salon? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau - **Literature is beautiful** :)

Comment: I must go to a bad salon.  Literature is the _last_ thing that is discussed :P

Answer (score -1):

**The Den of Enlightenment**

I like Library and The Reading room.  However, you don't talk in a library and you don't read in a chatroom.  You're "enlightened" when you read and discuss with others :)

Comment: It's a bit lengthy, I have to say.

Comment: Ah, but you *do* read in a chatroom.

Answer (score -6):

**Gutenberg** There is little that has more impact on literature then the work of [Johannes Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Gutenberg)

Answer (score -7):

**Gardeners and Architects**

Based on GRRM's [analysis](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/757256-i-often-said-that-writers-are-of-two-types-there) of the two types of writers.

Comment: I like the idea, but honestly this sounds more like a chatroom for [gardening.se].

Answer (score -10):

My suggestion:

Reader's Handbook

Answer (score -10):

### The bus

Because I read the most literature while traveling to or from work on public transport.